# Could I modify my DOM from within a class?

Tags: javascript, dom

It's really very simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I get "Uncaught TypeError: this.resizeCanvas is not a function" from the console in Chrome. The code is meant to resize the canvas in which I draw an analog clock.

<edit>
Pasting the entirety of the code, not just the protion giving me headache
</edit>

JAVASCRIPT

```
function Hands(canvas)
{
    this.angle = 0;
    this.beginX = canvas.width / 2;
    this.beginY = canvas.height / 2;
    this.endX = 0;
    this.endY = 0;
    this.radius = 0;
    this.length = 0;
    this.modLength = 0;
    this.color = '';
    this.lineCap = '';
    this.lineWidth = 0;
    this.rotation = ( Math.PI * 2 ) / 4;

    this.draw = function(ctx)
    {
        this.length = this.radius - this.modLength;

        this.endX = this.beginX + Math.cos( this.angle - this.rotation ) * this.length;
        this.endY = this.beginY + Math.sin( this.angle - this.rotation ) * this.length;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( this.beginX, this.beginY );
        ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.lineCap = this.lineCap;
        ctx.lineTo( this.endX, this.endY );
        ctx.stroke();
    };
}

function AnalogClock()
{
    this.canvas = document.getElementById( "clockface" );
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.margin = 30;
    this.rotation = (Math.PI * 2) / 4; // Rotate 0 rad to be at top of circle
    this.centerX = this.canvas.width / 2;
    this.centerY = this.canvas.height / 2;

    this.secondHand = new Hands(this.canvas);
    this.secondHand.lineWidth = 3;
    this.secondHand.modLength = 100;
    this.secondHand.beginX = this.centerX;
    this.secondHand.beginY = this.centerY;
    this.secondHand.color = '#ff0000';
    this.secondHand.radius = this.canvas.height / 2.031;

    this.minuteHand = new Hands(this.canvas);
    this.minuteHand.lineWidth = 10;
    this.minuteHand.modLength = 100;
    this.minuteHand.beginX = this.centerX;
    this.minuteHand.beginY = this.centerY;
    this.minuteHand.color = '#101010';
    this.minuteHand.radius = this.canvas.height / 2.031;

    this.hourHand = new Hands(this.canvas);
    this.hourHand.lineWidth = 16;
    this.hourHand.modLength = 175;
    this.hourHand.beginX = this.centerX;
    this.hourHand.beginY = this.centerY;
    this.hourHand.color = '#101010';
    this.hourHand.radius = this.canvas.height / 2.031;

    this.drawSecondHand = function( s )
    {
        this.secondHand.angle = ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( s / 60 );
        this.secondHand.draw( this.context );
    };

    this.drawMinuteHand = function( m )
    {
        this.minuteHand.angle = ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( m / 60 );
        this.minuteHand.draw( this.context );
    };

    this.drawHourHand = function( h )
    {
        this.hourHand.angle = ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( h / 12 );
        this.hourHand.draw( this.context );
    };

    this.drawDot = function( x, y, radius, radians, color )
    {
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc( x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false );
        this.context.fillStyle = color;
        this.context.fill();
    };

    this.drawClockFace = function()
    {
        var distance = this.centerY - 80;

        for( i = 0; i < 60; i++ )
        {
            var targetX = this.centerX + Math.cos( ( ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( i / 60 ) ) - this.rotation ) * distance;
            var targetY = this.centerY + Math.sin( ( ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( i / 60 ) ) - this.rotation ) * distance;

            this.drawDot( targetX, targetY, 3, this.minuteHand.color);
        }

        for( i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
        {
            var targetX = this.centerX + Math.cos( ( ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( i / 12 ) ) - this.rotation ) * distance;
            var targetY = this.centerY + Math.sin( ( ( Math.PI * 2 ) * ( i / 12 ) ) - this.rotation ) * distance;

            this.drawDot( targetX, targetY, 8, this.hourHand.color );
        }
    };

    this.resizeCanvas = function()
    {
        this.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth  - this.margin;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight - this.margin;
    };

    this.draw = function() 
    {
        var now = new Date();

        this.resizeCanvas();
        this.drawClockFace();
        this.drawHourHand( now.getHours() );
        this.drawMinuteHand( now.getMinutes() );
        this.drawSecondHand( now.getSeconds() );

        this.drawDot( this.centerX, this.centerY, 10, this.secondHand.color ); // Center dot
    };
}


/******** 
LOAD APP
*********/

// ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5); // Anti-aliasing

var analogClock = new AnalogClock();

function tick()
{
    setInterval( analogClock.draw, 1000 );
    analogClock.draw();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ tick(); });
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #fefefe;
            }

            canvas {
                background: #fefefe;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="root">
        <canvas id="clockface"></canvas>
        <script src="clock.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `myClock.resize();` ?

Comment: Tried that, but the error persisted. A blatant typo from my side.

Comment: Then you have another `function clock` that hides the one you showed.

Comment: Yeah if that was a typo then I see nothing else wrong with this snippet of code. Sounds like you've got something else interfering that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Please post some html as well or a JSFiddle recreating the issue. After changing `clock.resize()` to `myClock.resize()`, I am not getting errors in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjsga9ra/

Comment: This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lf0065ww/

Comment: I just create a test based on your code above and it works fine. I'm assuming that you're overriding your resize function elsewhere or something like that. Make sure that your clock definition is defined in the head of your document and definitely prior to actual use. I can post the code that I've used as an answer, if you wish.

Comment: Please do, it would be most helpful :)

Comment: Actually, I've spotted a few things wrong in your code. Your tick event is trying to do a setTimeout on the draw function of your clock. It should be drawing the clock and then calling setTimeout on tick instead. It does work after that. However, on doing that, my browser is running poorly due to the script. Not sure why. I haven't tried a requestAnimationFrame call yet, which may fix that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code your tick more like this...

```
function tick() {
    analogClock.draw();
    //setInterval(tick, 1000); - WRONG
    setTimeout(tick, 1000); // Or preferably use requestAnimationFrame.
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    tick();
});
```

However, when I do this, it runs very poorly in Firefox. Perhaps requestAnimationFrame will work better, but there's something that's locking it up that I can't quite put my finger on. However, this does resolve your current issue of resizeCanvas coming back as undefined. When you remove the tick and just call resizeCanvas or draw directly, they work fine. And once the tick is looping correctly, it also works fine.

I suspect the performance issue is being caused by the resize of the canvas being called on EVERY tick. You probably don't want to be doing that. You only need to call that, if the window is resized.

And the resultant clock is upside down BTW. In your Hands object, this corrects it...

```
this.rotation = -Math.PI / 2;
```

Comment: True, I should call it once at load to set the vars and then only on subsequent resizes. I'm not quiet sure why your solution works, but it does. I have a few cosmetic fixes to do as well. Will mark you answer as correct. Thank you :)

Comment: Your performance is slow because you are filling up the stack with calls to tick.  You need to use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: @PrestonS Yes. I just copied what the OP had above in their code. It should of course be setTimeout or via requestAnimationFrame. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that functions called by `setTimeout` and `setInterval` always have a `this` object of the current `window`.  When using either of these functions on an object's method, you must either use a wrapper function or use `apply()`

```
//wrapper
setTimeout(function(){analogClock.draw();}, 1000);
```

or

```
//apply
setTimeout(function(){analogClock.draw.apply(analogClock), 1000);
```

Instead you should write:

```
function tick()
{
    analogClock.draw();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ setInterval(tick, 1000); })
```

or

```
function tick()
{
    analogClock.draw();
    setInterval( analogClock.draw.apply(analogClock), 1000 );
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ tick(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `clock.resize()` to `myClock.resize()`.

Comment: Just a typo from my side when I copied the code to the site. It should as you say be `myClock.resize()`. The error is still present with or without the edit.